# Perl read CSV and manipulate dates and numbers

Tags: regex, csv, perl

I have run up to a problem and invested quite a few hours into understanding it...

I want to read a .csv file using perl, look for a date (and numbers), arrange the date to another format and add the numbers to an existing number.

The data in the .csv are simple fields with the ";" delimeter.

The date exists in the format 01.01.2000 in the .csv file and I would like to format ist to 2000-01-01. The amount exists in the form "-200".

Now the reading and putting it into variables works fine. 
However the variables dont behave like the others, I cannot properly use regex on them and if I try to add the amount to another vaiable I get the following error:
   Argument "\x{0}-\x{0}5\x{0},\x{0}6\x{0}6\x{0}" isn't numeric in addition (+)

Now it looks to me like there is an issue with the encoding of the data, that I did not handle correctly, but after several tries of "endode, decode, upgrade downgrade etc" I just can't get it to work.
And if I save these variables to a text file and open that manually, it tells me that the file is encoded in utf8 and for read-only.

What am I missing here and what do I need to understand concerning the encoding, I read a lot about it but I still don't really get it in my case.

Edit:
Sorry for my previous insufficient code. The following code should work on its own:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Text::CSV;
use Data::Dumper qw(Dumper);

my $file = "test.csv";
my $s_delimiter = ";";

open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die("ERROR open $file ($!)\n");

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({binary => 1, sep_char => $s_delimiter});

# read File
while( my $row = $csv->getline( $fh ) )
{
    my @array = @{$row};
    my $arraylength = @array;

    my $date = $array[2];
    my $amount = $array[6];

    $amount += 200;

    print "$amount\n";
    $date =~ /(\d\d).(\d\d).(\d\d\d\d)/;

    print "$date\n";
    print "$3 $2 $1\n";
}

close $fh;
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Looks like we might need to see more of your code. Your error talks about addition, but there's no addition in any of the code we can see. Also, it would be handy to see a sample input file. Perhaps you could put it online somewhere so we can see the encoding.

Comment: [Edit] the question and add a [example]. That is a complete, runable program that reproduces the error. Including the input, i.e. the CSV file in your case. **Do not** just post all of your code but a **minimized** version that just include everything needed to reproduce the error but nothing more.

Comment: You probably need to set the correct encoding on the filehandle that you're reading from. Do you know the encoding of the input file?

Comment: Thanks for the fast answers, code is updated. Is there a way to upload the .csv on here? Encoding seems to be UT-16

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comments I checked the encoding on the csv file and figured it out myself,
the line

```
open(my $fh, '<', $file) or die("ERROR open $file ($!)\n");
```

had to be changed into

```
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-16LE)', $file) or die("ERROR open $file ($!)\n");
```

since the encoding is UTF-16 which I did not realise at first.

But still thank you to the comments, they were the reason I found my error :)